# Firebase SSL Error Google API Certificate

Tags: ios, firebase, ssl, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am Using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8.3.3.

When I try to login using GoogleSignIn (using the Firebase pod) I get an SSL error:

`<Error> [Firebase/Core][I-NET901017] <Firebase/Network/ERROR> Encounter network error. Code, error: -1200, Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x608000240540 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}
2017-08-14 17:09:20.725 CinemaFile[46195] <Error> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000020] Error posting to Clearcut: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x608000240540 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0, _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9806, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9806}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made., NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://play.googleapis.com/log, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3}, with Status Code: 0`

This was working a short time ago - I have not changed any of my application's bundle identifiers or my GoogleService-info.plist

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Most of the time, it's as a result of poor connectivity into the network

Answer (score 1):

If you are using pods, try doing a pod update. I fixed mine just by doing that. Or maybe update your library.